# How to remove the Tools menu item from the WP-Admin menu

Tags: multisite, admin-menu

Where is function.php is stored and built? I want to remove menu named as tools from mysite from all user like admin and other user's?

I Request you please help me out from this problem.Give me the best solution like lay-man to wordpress so that i can understand things quickly.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [remove menu page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page).

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse26980_remove_tools', 99 );
function wpse26980_remove_tools()
{
    remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
}
```

You can drop that in your functions.php file (without the opening `<?php` most likely).

That's not going to prevent people from typing in `yoursite.com/wp-admin/tools.php` and seeing the tools page, however.

Answer (score 0):

The following code removes menus, place in your theme functions.php file:

```
// Remove unneeded menus
function sc_remove_menus()
{
    // setup the global menu variable
    global $menu;
    // this is an array of the menu item names we wish to remove
    $restricted = array( __('Links'),__('Tools'),__('Comments'), __('Media'));
    end ($menu);
    while (prev($menu))
    {
        $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
        if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted))
        {
            unset($menu[key($menu)]);
        }
    }
}
// hook into the action that creates the menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'sc_remove_menus');
```

If you just want to remove just tools then change this line:

```
$restricted = array( __('Links'),__('Tools'),__('Comments'), __('Media'));
```

to:

```
$restricted = array(__('Tools'));
```

This will only remove the menu item. You can still get to tools by typing in the URL manually.

Comment: This code is useful .

Comment: I think this code is useful. what I also have a question that where is functions.php is stored ? I stored it in  http://localhost/sandeep/nws/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/themes/functions.php it is not working sir .

Comment: I save this code like this in functions.php:-function sc_remove_menus()
{
    // setup the global menu variable
    global $menu;
    // this is an array of the menu item names we wish to remove
    $restricted = array(__('Tools'));
    
    end ($menu);
    while (prev($menu))
    {
        $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
        if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted))
        {
            unset($menu[key($menu)]);
        }
    }
}
// hook into the action that creates the menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'sc_remove_menus');

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use "Admin Menu Editor" plugin to easy manager Admin-cp menu ??!
Take a look on it, i'm using it for my current project, i want to say it's "perfect" !!!

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

Hope it can help you.
Regards,